# .htaccess issue: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, laravel-4, apache2

I am using Laravel, and have a problem with accessing parts of my app without appending `index.php` to the URL. After some research on SO, I gathered that I needed to:

1. Activate `rewrite_mod`,
2. Set `AllowOverride` to `All`

Which I have done. Yet after doing all of this, a couple of new problems arise. First I can't get access to the `public` folder, and I get the following error (when looking into `apache2/error.log`):

```
 [core:alert] [pid 15557] [client 87.81.146.231:56147] /var/www/data_exchange/laravel/public/.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context
```

Here's the `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine ON
    RewriteBase /laravel/  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here's what the `httpd.conf` (apache2.conf) looks like, I thought I'd add a new directory to see if it would fix the problem:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/data_exchange/laravel/public>
        Options Indexes followSymlinks
        allowoverride all
        require all granted
</Directory>
```

Ideally, I want users to be able to navigate through the app without the need of adding the index.php.

Answer (score 3):

try removing comment from line

```
RewriteBase /laravel/  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
```

Everything else looks good.

netfreehost @ FL

Comment: Thanks. Comments must be removed from the line!